# Настройка вида IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

В окне ИДЕА по правому борту вкладки: 7:Structure , Maven Project , Database и т.д.

Как настроить чтобы при запуске ИДЕА они всегда в определённом порядке (сверху вниз) , мной установленном, располагались?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вам поможет [Справка IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-menus-and-toolbars.html).